# Get FFT from a Wav after a hanning filter with 25% overlap?

Tags: fft, matlab, python

I have a program that allows me to record wav and get the FFT all at the same time.

However, the FFT I have I can't export it to work with. So I need to make a script to get it from the wav.

Can anyone give me a hand? The sample rate is 10kHz, the max frequency is 5000Hz, the resolution is 3.125 seconds, with a Hanning filtering with 25% overlap. The FFT I get is 1601 lines.

I don´t care if you do it in Python or in Matlab.